# SQL SERVER If procedure does not return rows

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way to specify condition - if procedure returns no rows? I would like to change this case for displaying something instead.

Yes, I mean it does not show table - that's the thing that i would like to condition.

In one sentence - If Proc does not show rows then select something .

Comment: A procedure shouldn't return anything, a function does it.

Comment: Could you provide a source of SP?  How do you run the Sp?